# A question about serial communication between two PC

Tags: serialport

I have PC1 and PC2. PC2 runs the PC2-software. And I need the remote PC1 to send some bytes to PC2 to control the PC2-software via a USB cable.

I tried to connect two PCs via a USB cable but I noticed this wont work.

How could that be done if both PCs do not have any RS232 port?

How would that be possible by using two USB-to-RS-232 adapter?(Both PCs dont have RS232 port)

Will the following work?:

PC1->USB-to-RS232 adapter1->----|"DB9 cable"|----<-USB-to-RS232 adapter2<-PC2

And what type of DB9 cable must be used?

Comment: You can just tunnel a connection over ethernet.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, how long is the distance between PCs, and what speed do you expect? Also, why serial instead of Ethernet? That defines if you even want a serial port at all, and whether or not an RS-232 connection can even do it or not.

Comment: There are [bridging USB cables](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005OTPVMY) and they work for data transfers between PCs.

Comment: @periblepsis These sure exist, but won't look like serial ports, require proprietary drivers and file transfer program. As they are not serial ports no program you already have that wants to open serial ports will see it as a serial port and can't open it. You can't send arbitrary bytes through them, not unless you reverse-engineer how to do it. Oh and it's Windows only.

Comment: @Justme So they do not register themselves as HID? I'll see if I can find a bridging USB cable that does register under some default HID... Probably exists, but I don't know for now.

Comment: @periblepsis At least the cable you linked to does not register as HID if the website says drivers are needed. Also driverless COM ports are not HID, they are CDC-ACM, so any HID device will not show as serial COM port.

Comment: @Justme Interesting. I regularly use devices that register themselves as virtual COM ports and I think I read somewhere that these are HID. I certainly never needed to install any drivers. Windows just recognized the devices, entirely automatically. I guess you are telling me that I misunderstand what I thought I'd read and that they are CDC. A new term to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Justme Thinking about this, I can see that USB bridging would only make marketing sense if there was also a lot of speed involved. Virtual COM ports would not qualify. So that suggests I'll have a hard time finding a so-called "bridge" cable that uses FTDI as the connection means as a COTS product. Probably left up to DIY, I guess. I'll keep my eyes peeled for someone making a COTS product that uses FTDI or compatible Chinese chips between two USB hubs that registers on both ends as virtual COM. I could get lucky. ;) Never needed one and don't know. But your education is making me curious.

Comment: @periblepsis Why virtual COM ports would not qualify? Virtual means they don't really need to be actual UARTs and they don't need an actual baud rate, they are virtual and can pass data as fast as they possibly can through an IC. Just like you can install virtual serial ports that are not physical or work through Ethernet. But this is getting off-topic.

Comment: @Justme My ignorance, mostly. I do already understand the fact that a virtual com port doesn't need an actual bit rate (heck, I've written lots of code already using them with MCUs.) But my limited usage has been with FTDI and a few other minor incarnations. While they present (with help) to the USB hub, the other end is actually tied to a bit rate being asynch that I can monitor with an MSO. Is there an IC that would register itself with both hubs as virtual com ports? And yes, my ignorance is definitely off-topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A USB to RS-232 cable will have a Male DB-9 connector. Use a *null modem* Female to Female DB-9 cable to connect them. A null modem cable will cross the Tx and Rx lines.

Or, skip the DB-9 connectors. Buy USB to female header serial adapters. Connect these with male headers. Cross the Rx and Tx yourself.

Comment: So I need a long cable null modem Female to Female DB-9 cable and two USB to RS-232 adapters. I think your first option is what I look for.

Comment: 9 pin connectors are unlikely to come in B size. You must mean DE-9.

Comment: @Justme - DB9 is the commonly used terminology, even if it is technically incorrect.